# Change display language for pinned directories/locations

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

On Ubuntu 14.04 / Gnome Classic I changed the display language from English to Italian. I also confirmed that user directories should be renamed.

However, references to user directories in *Places* (*Posizioni*) menu still show English names

[image: screenshot]

They also stopped working, because they point to wrong directories.
Eg. clicking on *Documents* results in an error saying that *~/Documents* doesn't exist (because it's now *~/Documenti*).

How can I fix this? Where can I edit or remove them?

I already checked that:

- *.config/user-dirs.dirs* contains correct paths
- *.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks* contains correct paths (bookmarks shown on the screenshot with Italian names work fine).

Comment: I didn't... I only logged out&logged in and somehow assumed it's enough. Works fine now, thanks @Braiam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restart the system for the changes to take effect, a simple login/out isn't enough.